# How to specify two or more conditions within find() method in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model

I'm having problems fetching data using `Model::find()` with two conditions. I want to return one record that has the given `member_id` **AND** its `role` is `guest`:

```
$member = CalendarMembers::find(["member_id" => $r->member_id, "role" => "guest"]);
```

But this isn't working. I have one user that when created, a new register is added to `calendar_members` table specifying this user as `parent`, yet, when attempting to fetch this user automatically created by just giving the `member_id`, it will be fetched, which **SHOULD NOT**.

I cannot use other ways such as:

```
$member = \DB::table("calendar_members")->where([ ["member_id", "=", $r->member_id], ["role", "=", "guest"] ])->first();
```

Because then `$member->delete()` or `$member->destroy()` will throw an error saying either `delete` or `destroy` do not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find()` method uses ID to get a record. You need to use the `where()` and `first()` methods:

```
CalendarMembers::where(['member_id' => $r->member_id, 'role' => 'guest'])->first();
```

Comment: It solved, much appreciated. I must've overlooked in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

you should use where for multiple conditions and get the first row with first() method, find is basically an alias for wehre('id', $id)

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear, find() method will perform database query and returns single model object as result. so find is equal to,

```
Model::where('id', 1)->first().
```

`find()` returns Model object and `where()` returns QueryBuilder. But you can directly perform on query Builder without fetching model, like,

```
Model::where('id', 1)->delete().
```

REF : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent